# TinyOS: How can I convert uint_16 to two uint_8 integers (AES encryption)

Tags: c, aes, tinyos

I am using the Oscilloscope component to read sensor data.  I'm sending this data to a basestation mote which is sending the data to a laptop.

I want to implement AES encryption on the sensor data using the components provided here: http://tinyos.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tinyos/tinyos-2.x-contrib/crypto/index.html

My plan is to reduce the data buffer from 10 to 8 in Oscilloscope.h.  This changes the total data size to 128 bits (the same as a block size in AES).  Now the only problem is each array element in the AES block is a unit_8, but the array elements of the data buffer are uint_16.

Is there anyway I can 'split' a uint_16 value to the upper and lower bits?  I would then store them as 2 elements in my AES block array.

To clarify, I have a uint_16 which corresponds to some data read by the sensor.  I want to be able to store this value in 2 uint_8 values.  I will then encrypt the data block, send the packet to the basestation, and the basestation will decrypt and combine the values to the original uint_16.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just store the least significant eight bits in one variable, and the most significant eight in the other

```
unit8_t low = value & 0xFF;
uint8_t high = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

(the bitwise and is superfluous in both cases since the conversion to `uint8_t` is specified to do the same).

To retrieve the `uint16_t` value from the parts, you need a shift and a bitwise or,

```
uint16_t reassembled = ((uint16_t)high << 8) | low;
```

Since the integer promotions are performed on the arguments of the shift operator, the cast to `uint16_t` is not necessary if `int` is more than 16 bits wide, but if `int` is exactly 16 bits wide, the shift can lead to undefined behaviour because the value `high*256` need not be representable as an `int` then, so to be safe, a cast is needed before the shift. If `int` is 16 bits wide, the `uint16_t` obtained from the cast will then be converted to an `unsigned int` - unless you have a perverse implementation where the width of `unsigned int` is smaller than that of `int` - otherwise to `int`, but that's wide enough then.

Comment: To combine them would I just reverse the operations?  I would do a left shift on high then bitwise and both values?